# cabal dependencies are missing in Yesod and stack

Tags: haskell, yesod, cabal-install, haskell-stack

Hi i try to create a new proyect for yesod using stack, follow the [quickstart](http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart) tutorial; to create the scaffolding I use the command:

```
stack new my-project yesod-postgres && cd my-project
```

But when run `stack exec -- yesod devel` get:

```
cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
classy-prelude >=0.10.2,
classy-prelude-conduit >=0.10.2,
classy-prelude-yesod >=0.10.2,
data-default -any,
hjsmin >=0.1 && <0.3,
monad-logger ==0.3.*,
persistent >=2.0 && <2.6,
persistent-postgresql >=2.1.1 && <2.6,
persistent-template >=2.0 && <2.6,
safe -any,
yesod >=1.4.3 && <1.5,
yesod-auth >=1.4.0 && <1.5,
yesod-core >=1.4.17 && <1.5,
yesod-form >=1.4.0 && <1.5,
yesod-static >=1.4.0.3 && <1.6
```

I try with the command `stack exec -- cabal install` but get:

```
cabal: Use of GHC's environment variable GHC_PACKAGE_PATH is incompatible with
Cabal. Use the flag --package-db to specify a package database (it can be used multiple times).
```

Thanks for the help

**EDIT**

The command to install the postgres library in ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libpq-dev
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As described in the [Yesod quick start page](http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart), you have to do this inside the project:

```
stack build yesod-bin cabal-install --install-ghc
stack build
```

And then,

```
stack exec -- yesod devel
```

Comment: thanks you are right my error was that run the command outside of the project; but it only work for the sqlite template; the postgres template send a error message when run `stack build` get:  `You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application`

Comment: @oriaj For postgres, you have to most likely install the server library separately.